# Portable 3-Lead Auto-Diagnosing EKG

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, medical

I am designing a 3-Lead portable Auto-Diagnosing EKG for a HS Science fair.  I saw an opportunity where the device was lacking or could be improved.  I know from my own experiences that at my schools and many other public places the staff have little if any clue of how to approach or deal with any medical matters concerning the heart.  As a result of my findings I started developing this portable EKG which could be worn for approx. 5-10min and diagnose the issue along with the severity of the case in an easy to understand manner, so that anyone could simply attach the device and relay the information to medical professionals, and deal with the case appropriatly.  With the device being portable, quick diagnosing, and cheap I understand that the accuracy cannot be 100% nor did I want the device to reach such a high accuracy as it would raise the cost,  it's for the same reason that I did not want the device to diagnose advanced issues such as hypertrophy.  The goal is really to quickly examine the patient and determine the risk level so that the appropriate action can be taken rather then shooting for the high level accuracy that the medical 12-leads go for.  The current input stream is being run through a Pan-Tompkins Algorithm that filters the input stream and isolates the QRS.  The current issue arising is the conversion of the QRS input to a value to which the auto-diagnosis can work off of.  I would greatly appreciate any form of help or advice on the matter and all responses are thoroughly appreciated!

Thank you,
Benjamin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually its mainly concerned with coding rather then electronics